# How to decide between SQLite database vs. in-memory usage

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, memory

I inherited a project from a colleague that left the company. While examining his code, I got confused by something. After he receives quite a big amount of data from the server, he saves this data to a database in the client and then he goes on to work with this data on db. The data is received once at the beginning of the application. What I could not understand that much is, why isn't he just using the data from the memory but needs to store this on db?

Inside the application there are many memory intensive operations like viewing big pdf files using Quartz and so, but isn't the sqlite's size also counted as the memory usage of the app? I mean what do you think the advantage of this could be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQLite have very small footprint when load itself (~250-400Kb). When SQLite work with on-disk database, there is no memory overhead because of it, it don't even meter size of the file (by default database can hold about 1Tb of data in it's tables). And as you said, it's persistent data storage.

In case of in-memory database store, your application wil consume

```
memory = database file size + small overhead
```

Also yo will get some amount of limitations with queries you can perform on in-memory database (I can't remember for time I on the street, but you can't use transactions and vacuum)

Use SQLite with on-disk database and you will gain faster data access and lower footprint than trying to use files to store set of data

Comment: Ok to make it clear I'm going to ask this: For example, when the client receives 300 dictionaries that hold big objects, would the memory footprint of the application be lower if the client keeps using these objects from the memory or would it be lower when it saves them to sqlite and uses from there?

Comment: If object allows, they can be placed into sqlite database which will reduce application memory footprint.

Comment: And that would be because sqlite would keep the objects on the file system, not the memory of the device, right?

Comment: Yes, when I said _on-disk_ I mean on NAND (device flash memory, which used to store applications, photos and so on).

Answer (score 5):

With SQLite you can quickly and easily query for specific data without having to load the entire dataset into memory and iterate over it.

Comment: oh yes, it suits a lot when I think about the data structures throughout the app

Comment: Both answers have their different aspects, but I had to choose one. I wish I could accept more than one answers at the same time :) Thx again!

Answer (score 3):

Basically, if you keep it on the local file system and load it into memory on demand, this will always have a lower (or equal) memory footprint than if you have ALL data loaded into memory at all times.  If you keep everything on the file system, this will save memory because you don't have to have everything loaded (into memory) at once, and even when something is loaded it quickly closes.  The downside to this is slower access times, translating to decreased real world performance under very heavy loads.

On the other hand, if you keep everything loaded into memory, it will have a much higher memory footprint, compensated by a much faster database access time.  You will have better real world performance under very high loads (assuming you can accomodate the memory usage), but a much higher memory footprint.

Your choice should be based on the needs and specs of the system you are operating on.  If you aren't sure, try loading everything into memory and see if you have problems on your server during periods of heavy load.  If it is not working, go back to the hard drive.